# Stripe payment vendor related issue

Tags: magento, stripe-payments, magento2, stripes

i have platform magento 2.my website is b2b. website used stripe payment. we are using multivendor for magento 2. i have found some issue.my platform in france we are saw that for sellers in Brazil Stripe can't process my commission.

for example Is the total amount for the seller, like the 90 euros in the example below?
Cost of product: 100 euros
Vendor amount: 90 euros
Platform commission: 10 euros

i have the below link for stripe. but I have no idea. so please help me.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/service-agreement-types#recipient

Comment: You should contact Stripe [support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) with details of your account and the payment in question.

Comment: @JonathanSteele we did not proper solution and support from the striped team. so do you have any idea above issue? or suggestion on your end. then let us known.